# Add filtering options to the column header of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, filter

I need a way to filter a JTable by clicking on the column header. Ideally, a click on a column header would show a drop-down list with unique values corresponding to that column. One or more values can then be selected to filter the JTable.

I did a bit of research and came across the [swingbits](https://github.com/eugener/oxbow) library, which does the job. But I was wondering if there were any other built in (or external) java libraries that would allow me to accomplish this.

Comment: there are a lot of Swing libraries out there. I am sure JGoodies and JIDE would have that component that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Could not find any in-built libraries that provided the required functionality. Found another external library called [TableFilter](http://coderazzi.net/tablefilter/) that has a pretty good set of features. But it does have some short comings like the inability to select multiple values for a filter and the filter not actually being on the table header. 
Went ahead with Swing Bits which is the closest match for my needs.